# is it necessary to place font property in order

Tags: css, fonts

- This is an excerpt from the code:

  ```
  #text {
      font: 20pt italic bold arial;
      color: blue;
  }
  ```

It just increase the size, but is not italic nor bold.

- But doing so, does the work:

  ```
  #text {
      font: italic bold 20pt arial;
      color: blue;
  }
  ```

Is it necessary to place all the properties in order? Or is there some other problem? I am confused. Please help me understand. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a link to the Mozilla developer network that states the order that is necessary for the shorthand `font` to work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font - At the bottom of this page there is a form that will help create the shorthand `font` you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must maintain the order. For more info view the below image for ordering:

[image]

[source](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 0):

Look in documentation:

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height|caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit;
```

> The properties that can be set, are (in order): "font-style
>   font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family"

So yes, it must be in it's predefined order to parse correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I avoid using the `font` property at all times.

Here is a more compatible way:

```
#text {
 font-size: 20pt
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: arial;
 color: blue;
}
```

I would avoid using font, simply because it is much easier to read and maintain your css code in the long run.  reading a long string for one css property seems like bad juju to me!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to put the font properties in the order defined in the specifications, if you use the [`font` shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand). The reason to this isn’t just that the specs say so. They say many things that are not actually enforced; this one is. The definition of the shorthand means that anything after the font size value (here `20pt`) is taken as a font family list. Here it does not have any space, so the string `italic bold arial` is taken as a font family name. It is a formally valid name (contrary to popular belief, quotation marks are generally not required around such a name by CSS syntax), but no font family with that name exists. So the declaration, equivalent to

```
font: 20pt "italic bold arial"
```

is formally valid, but can affect only the font size.

(If you use a browser’s developer tools, you will probably see that the above is how the declaration is parsed.)