# CSS font: bold; only working in some instances?

Tags: css

So i'm trying out `font:`  in my css code, which is the shorthand for `font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family`.

And while im trying to use **bold**, sometimes it works & sometimes it dosnt.
(i'm using Chrome)

a) font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;                        WORKS

b) font: italic bold 15px Arial, sans-serif;            WORKS

c) font: italic small-caps bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;   WORKS

d) font: bold 15px Arial, sans-serif;                       WORKS

e) font: bold Arial, sans-serif;                            DOSNT WORK

f) font: italic bold;                                       DOSNT WORK

g) font: bold;                                              DOSNT WORK

Yes I realise I could just `font-weight: bold;` , but I want to understand why some of the above is working and some isn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it necessary to place font property in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847477/is-it-necessary-to-place-font-property-in-order)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#syntax

Comment: Thanks CBroe, after reading your stackoverflow link, there are 'Optional' & 'Mandatory'  properties to use with the font shorthand. Font-size & Font-family must be declared otherwise other properties will not work.